# How to set max scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say that we have body width of page set to 2000px with content centered horizontally inside of body with width set to 1200px.

```
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 2000px;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that I do not allow horizontal scrolling at all until your 
window size is 1200px or less (on resize) with setting overflow-x to hidden.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(window.innerWidth > 1200) {
            $("body").css({
                "overflow-x": "hidden"
            });
        } else {
            $("body").css({
                "overflow-x": "visible"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

which works fine. But I also want to prevent user from scrolling further than 1200px if his window width is less than 1200px (problem here is that as soon as the window width is less than 1200px, it is possible to scroll to full width - 2000px).

So how would you solve this?

Comment: So basically you want the content to be fixed at `1200px`, with a `margin-left` of `400px`, until one gets down to a screen size of `1200px`?

Comment: No, I don't want margin-left to be set to 400px, it is set to auto so that the content is always centered.

Comment: Don't use JS to hijack the scroll event, but instead set the element's width to 1200px so users cannot scroll further.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then I believe this could be fixed by adding a max width style to your body tag. This eliminated side scroll for me.

```
body {
    max-width: 2000px;  
}
```

Comment: If you set max-width to 2000px then you will be able to scroll to 2000px. I want the body to be 2000px width but only allow to scroll to 1200px.

Comment: In that case I dont think you need to give the body a width. If you leave it blank then the user's window size should dictate the body size. Then the scroll wont be affected. Can you elaborate a bit more on why you need the background that wide? More information would be helpful figuring out a fix.

Comment: I need a fixed size because I do not want the picture (which covers the body) to respond to size of the window other than it is always centered (the picture should not get any smaller or bigger). And it is also the same reason why I need body that wide - because of the picture.

Comment: There is no way to resize the image so that it still looks good? what kind of image / layout is that, that doesn't sound like good design?

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can use the scrollLeft proprerty:

```
onScroll = function (e){
   var maxScroll=1200
   if(e.target.scrollLeft>maxScrollLeft){
     e.target.scrollLeft=maxScrollLeft 
   }
}
```